# Process Builder not triggered by Data Importer

Tags: salesforce

We have a Process Builder set up to populate some fields. Nice and simple, and works fine when manually inserting a record.

However, when using the Data Imported to import a CSV, the Process never gets triggered. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce system cannot distinguish between a user updating a record and the record being updated through a data loader. The data loader inserted record must not be satisfying the process builders "start condition" or criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Some time process builder having issue with updating bulk record execution, it mainly happen when u used data loader you can do one thing reduce batch size for data loader.

or else u can follow this link :-
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230650&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 0):

We have to enable the setting  "Trigger workflow rules and processes for new and updated records" on Import wizard when we launch import wizard and select an object.

[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiG8X.png)